# Extracting text between values in txt file using php

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to extract the values between eng_tid

and eng_data for http://fdguirhgeruih.x10.mx/html.txt and I keep getting T string errors.

why do I keep getting errors

```
<? php

    //First, open the file. Change your filename
    $file = "http://fdguirhgeruih.x10.mx/html.txt";
    $word1='tid';
    $word2='data';


    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
    fclose($handle);

    $between=substr($contents, strpos($contents, $word1), strpos($contents, $word2) - strpos($contents, $word1));

    echo $between; 


    ?>
```

Comment: Please *always* quote the exact error messages you are getting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** after seeing error messages...

Instead of `fread()` and attempting to use the size in bytes of your target file, you may simply use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve the remote file.  Your error is because PHP wants to read the filesize of the file as though it is local, but it is a remote file over HTTP. `filesize()` reports 0 and an error.  Instead do

```
// Don't do this...
//$handle = fopen($file, "r");
//$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
//fclose($handle);

// Instead do this...
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: @RacquelAitken You need to post your errors, and more of your code if this isn't all of it.

Comment: Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://fdguirhgeruih.x10.mx/html.txt in /home/regerger/public_html/extract.php on line 10

Warning: fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /home/regerger/public_html/extract.php on line 10

Comment: @RacquelAitken I understand now - see my update and use `file_get_contents()` instead of `fopen()/fread()`

Comment: <code><?php

    //First, open the file. Change your filename
    $file = "http://fdguirhgeruih.x10.mx/html.txt";
    $word1='eng_tid';
    $word2='eng_type';
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $between=substr($contents, strpos($contents, $word1), strpos($contents, $word2) - strpos($contents, $word1));

    echo $between; 


    ?></code>

Comment: @RacquelAitken Running this code I get back a long string from the file.

Comment: it keeps giving me a blank page

Comment: @RacquelAitken Code is exactly as you have posted in the comment. My first test yesterday returned something, whether it was your intended output or not. Today, the contents of the resource are different, and do not contain your keywords. Browse directly to the file to see for yourself: http://fdguirhgeruih.x10.mx/html.txt